# Prism SetProptery not firing Notification?

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

So having a play with `PRISM` and I have a grid who's `Visibility` property is bound to a property in a view model like so.

Xaml

```
Grid Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Background="#7F808080" Visibility="{Binding LoadingVisibility}">
```

Code Behind

```
private Visibility loadingVisibility = Visibility.Visible;

public Visibility LoadingVisibility
{
    get
    {
        return loadingVisibility;
    }
    set
    {
        SetProperty(ref loadingVisibility, value);
    }
}
```

Now if I do this  `LoadingVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;`, the grid does not disappear and is still visible.

If I then set a breakpoint at `SetProperty(ref loadingVisibility, value);` I can see the original value of `loadingVisibility`, which is set as `Visibile`, and I can see that `value` is set to `Collapsed`.
If I then step on I can see `loadingVisiblity` has now changed to `collapsed` as it should. At this point I expect the `Grid` to be notified which in turn executes 'Get' to retrieve the value. This does not occur.

The binding is working because the `Get` is called when loading up and if I change `private Visibility loadingVisibility = Visibility.Visible;` to `Collapsed` and run the code the grid starts invisible.

So my question is, after `SetProperty` is executed, why is the `Get` not?

EDIT:
Just so you can see where I set the property.

```
public ShellViewModel(IEventAggregator IEventAggregator)
{
      IEventAggregator.GetEvent<PubSubEvent<HardwareLoaded>>().Subscribe(x =>
      {
          if (!x.HardwareOK)
          {
              MessageBox.Show("There was an issue loading hardware. See Log");
          }

          LoadingVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;           
       });
}
```

EDIT 2:
Just found something interesting, if I comment out `LoadingVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;` in the `Subscribe` and then add a button to the xaml and have the click event like so then everything works fine.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
      mvm.LoadingVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

So now I guess the question is why, when both methods call the set property, does only one fully work and cause the `Get` to work?

Comment: No its in a subscribe of an EventAggregator. I have placed a breakpoint there and it does get executed.

Comment: Check the **Output Window** for binding errors.

Comment: @MikeEason already done that and couldn't see any.

Comment: Looks like your binding somehow works in `OneTime` mode. Have you tried to explicitly setup the binding as `Mode=OneWay`?

Comment: @dymanoid Just tried all the options and all of them resulted in the same out come.

Comment: If the binding is correct and no output error, and the value actaully changes then it should work. If the value was the same, the notification would not be triggered. If you tried mode=twoway then I don't see why it would not work. Have you tied implementing your own INotifyPropertyChanged just to see whether you get the same behaviour?

Comment: your viewModel does not have INPC implementation so it is not notifying the UI for the property changed.

Comment: @Nikita the ViewModel derives from BindableBase which implements the INPC, does it not?

Comment: Oh,yes.You are 100% correct.

Comment: To check whether the viewmodel raises the `PropertyChanged` event, you can subscribe to it and set a break point in the event handler. I'm pretty sure this works, so there is something wrong with your bindings, styles etc.

Comment: @dymanoid I'm thinking the same about the binding but then if you look at my Edit 2 the binding seems to be fine when using a button to set the property.

Comment: Not sure if this could be the problem, but have you tried to explicitly handle the event on the UI thread? `.Subscribe(x => { .. }, ThreadOption.UIThread);`

Comment: @Bart That got it! Post an answer and I will mark it :-D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite often when using the `EventAggregator`, you're working on the UI thread. But seeing the `HardwareLoaded` type it came to me that you might be doing some checking on another thread. And as we know, bindings have to be updated from the UI thread. Normally you would use Dispather.BeginInvoke, but Prism's EventAggregator has an overload in the Subscribe method to tell the handler to offload to the UI thread.

```
IEventAggregator.GetEvent<PubSubEvent<HardwareLoaded>>().Subscribe(x =>
{
    if (!x.HardwareOK)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("There was an issue loading hardware. See Log");
    }

    LoadingVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}, ThreadOption.UIThread);
```

Comment: Bindings don't have to be updated on UI thread, because WPF automatically dispatches the `PropertyChanged` event to the main thread. So any scalar property may be updated in any thread. For collections, this is not true.